# Media Queries переписывают друг друга

Tags: css3, media-queries

Возникла проблема при использовании `media queries`. Вот скрин проблемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: lenovonuj@gmail.com пишите , попробую решить

Comment: @Geyan, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему, ваши медиа-запросы работают правильно. Чтобы в этом убедиться, выполните в консоли `window.innerWidth + 'x' + window.innerHeight` и увидите размер `viewport` эмулятора устройства.

Чтобы ваши медиа-запросы работали, как вы ожидаете, нужно добавить

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```